# Alternative for ADAL in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, token, adal

Is there any alternative for **ADAL**. I have created SharePoint hosted app. For every new build app deployed with new url with new `Id` like

> https://mysite-**a08081eeabb935**.sharepoint.com/sites/test/myApp

For the authentication **token** I need to go to the application in **Azure Active Directory** and have to add the reply url. It is ok but for every new build i have to change the reply url.

I want to publish app in office store, If client install app in their environment then app url will change then How can I fetch url from their environment.

Finally I have to add reply url of app in AAD for authentication. I want solution so that for all customer the url will be same or may be an alternative for adal 
Is there any possible alternate way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you need the token?

Comment: to authenticate user for outlook intergration

Comment: Have you tried using ADAL JS? https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/tree/dev

Comment: yes. With Adal js i have to add reply url each time

Comment: If you expose this app in the Office store, how do you expect to be able to add an app to your customer's Azure Active Directory? I don't think you have a workable solution here.

Comment: Thats why I need alternate for AAD

Comment: Is there any possible solution?

Comment: The problem is to use ADAL JS on SharePoint hosted app, because of CORS issues, and having to use integrated sharepoint web proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use ADAL JS authentication inside SharePoint hosted App. The problem is with SharePoint integrated http proxy and CORS support.
If you build SharePoint provider hosted app, and register the App inside Azure AD, you can use ADAL and get token and access Microsoft Graph REST API and SharePoint Online resources.